# Scrapping NSE 52 week high Table using Python

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm relatively new to web scrapping , I used Selenium and beautiful soup to srcape data however I'm unable to, Can someone help get the table data from the following link or any way to download the CSV file in Python please?

'''

```
print("Start")
from nsetools import Nse
import pandas as pd
import requests
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time

import urllib.request
nse_web = "https://www.nseindia.com/market-data/new-52-week-high-low-equity-market"
req = urllib.request.Request(
    nse_web, 
    data=None, 
    headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/105.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'}
)
#f = urllib.request.urlopen(req)

#nse_web = "https://www.nseindia.com/market-data/new-52-week-high-low-equity-market"
time.sleep(5)
html = urlopen(req)
print("open URL")
time.sleep(10)
bsObj = BeautifulSoup(html, features="lxml")
print("before_table")
time.sleep(15)
data = []
table = soup.find('table', attrs={'class':'common_table customHeight-table tableScroll alt_row w-100'})
print(table)
table_body = table.find('tbody')
print(table_body)

rows = table_body.find_all('tr')
Print(rows)
for row in rows:
    cols = row.find_all('td')
    cols = [ele.text.strip() for ele in cols]
    data.append([ele for ele in cols if ele]) # Get rid of empty values

print(data)
print("process complete")
```

'''

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you are able to get the data from the table as a list of rows. To make a csv file you need to use python csv module.

```
import csv
with open('result.csv', 'wb') as csv_file:
  csv_obj = csv.writer(csv_file)
  for row in data:
    csv_obj.writerow(row)
```

you can obtain your `results.csv` file in your current directory.

Comment: Hi @Fierylon , if we are executing the code - it goes into infinite loop and urlopen is unable to open the link because that website do not allow bots so was looking for a way around.

Comment: If we run the code it doesn't it only prints "Start" apart from that I don't get any other prints

Comment: Okay you can try to use selenium module. It cannot be easily detected, Apart from that if you need to make your table as a csv file then you can use the codes i provided to you